# Dynamic Tailwind Component Grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im mapping a list of js components into a grid containing one row, and 12 columns. I want to use only 6 columns, with the other 6 used as padding of 3 columns on both edges of the grid. I want to put three elements (spanning two columns each) starting at column 4, then column 6, then column 8. It seems that dynamically declaring the col-start-${variable} doesn't work, and cannot think of another way to do this.
On top of this, I get a unique key error, and cannot fix that either. Ive tried many other solutions, to no success.

Header.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import contact from "../data/contact";

function Header() {
    return (
        <section>
            <h1 className="text-5xl font-medium">
                Title
            </h1>
            <div className="grid grid-cols-12">
                {contact.map((item, index) => (
                    <div key={item.key} id={item.key} className={`col-start-${index*(index+1)+4}`}>
                        <div className="flex flex-row bg-white p-3 font-bold border border-1">
                            {item.svg}
                            <h1 className="self-center pl-3">{item.title}</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </section>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

contact.js:

```
const contact = [
    //Phone
    {
        key: "phoneSVG",
        svg: [
            <svg
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                fill="black"
                className="w-8 h-8"
            >
                <path
                    fillRule="evenodd"
                    d="M1.5 4.5a3 3 0 013-3h1.372c.86 0 1.61.586 1.819 1.42l1.105 4.423a1.875 1.875 0 01-.694 1.955l-1.293.97c-.135.101-.164.249-.126.352a11.285 11.285 0 006.697 6.697c.103.038.25.009.352-.126l.97-1.293a1.875 1.875 0 011.955-.694l4.423 1.105c.834.209 1.42.959 1.42 1.82V19.5a3 3 0 01-3 3h-2.25C8.552 22.5 1.5 15.448 1.5 6.75V4.5z"
                    clipRule="evenodd"
                />
            </svg>,
        ],
        title: "Phone",
    },

    //Mail
    {
        key: "mailSVG",
        svg: [
            <svg
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                fill="black"
                className="w-8 h-8"
            >
                <path d="M1.5 8.67v8.58a3 3 0 003 3h15a3 3 0 003-3V8.67l-8.928 5.493a3 3 0 01-3.144 0L1.5 8.67z" />
                <path d="M22.5 6.908V6.75a3 3 0 00-3-3h-15a3 3 0 00-3 3v.158l9.714 5.978a1.5 1.5 0 001.572 0L22.5 6.908z" />
            </svg>,
        ],
        title: "Email",
    },

    //Download
    {
        key: "downloadSVG",
        svg: [
            <svg
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                fill="black"
                className="w-8 h-8"
            >
                <path
                    fillRule="evenodd"
                    d="M19.5 21a3 3 0 003-3V9a3 3 0 00-3-3h-5.379a.75.75 0 01-.53-.22L11.47 3.66A2.25 2.25 0 009.879 3H4.5a3 3 0 00-3 3v12a3 3 0 003 3h15zm-6.75-10.5a.75.75 0 00-1.5 0v4.19l-1.72-1.72a.75.75 0 00-1.06 1.06l3 3a.75.75 0 001.06 0l3-3a.75.75 0 10-1.06-1.06l-1.72 1.72V10.5z"
                    clipRule="evenodd"
                />
            </svg>,
        ],
        title: "Download CV",
    },
];

export default contact;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do that naturally.
Tailwind `just-in-time` process is why.

How Tailwind basically works is, at build time, it will scrape every single of the folders in `content` of his config.
Any classes found at build time in those folders is considered "used", and so, included in the final delivered to client .css file, automatically.

That is made to make sure to have the smallest CSS, and to purge no-more-used classes.

**But,** you can use `safelist` in the config, although the Tailwind Team does not recommend abusing it, in your case, it is in my opinion fine. You can [find the documentation of it here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes).

Safelist will basically make sure that no matter if scrapped or not, these classes are included.